# I would like to make my image pop out larger when I click on it

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I am new to HTML,CSS and Javascript. I am trying to get my picture to pop out larger when I click on it but I do not know how to implement it. I have been trying to find a good Javascript tutorial but explain a technique for this. Please Help. (All I have right know is the code to put the image on the web page).

I would like it to look something like this.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_popup_image

but they do not show the javascript in the tutorial

Comment: Could you add the code you have? You may not need JavaScript. You may be able get the job done with CSS.

Answer (score 6):

```css
body {
  padding: 3em;
}

img {
  transition: transform .5s;
}

img:hover {
  transform: scale(2.5);
}
```

```html
<img src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/9708ca3dca5969e124d0730acf48d2e7?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">
```

See http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d and http://caniuse.com/#search=transition for more details about browser support and vendor prefixes.

Comment: this works great but how would I get the image to pop up in a new window like this. http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_popup_image

Answer (score 3):

Try this. Change the src with your image name.
Regards!

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .pop-out
    {
        transition: transform .5s;
    }

    .pop-out:hover
    {
        -ms-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
        transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="test.jpg" class="pop-out">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unprefixed version have to be the last.

Comment: this works great but how would I get the image to pop up in a new window like this. http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_popup_image

Comment: I honestly don't understand your doubt. The link you provided have the answer :)

Comment: @alexandergs Its not popping out or closing as smooth

Comment: @Cscience18 I don't recall that smoothness was a requirement. Nevertheless, you can add the following to the .pop-out class: .pop-out{ transition: transform .5s;
}

Comment: @alexandergs, thank you for your answer. I tried this today, 03/2024, it still works.

Answer (score 0):

I have two great solutions :)

---

### *Option 1)*

**HTML**

```
<img id="image" src="">
```

**CSS**

```
#image {
    width: 100%;
}
#image:hover {
    width: 150%;
}
```

---

### *Option 2)*

**HTML**

```
<img id="image" src="">
```

**CSS**

```
#image {
    width: 100%;
}
#image:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

---

So simply, in both examples I am increasing the image size by 50%. Now the two ways to do this are make a bigger `width`, or use `scale(x.x)`.

I hope I could help! :)